# ! Misplaced \omit error when inputting table with multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn, input

I am building a table from several components that I automatically export from STATA. For this, I use `\input{}` to input the components inside a table and tabular environment. This usually works well, but I now want to input a line that contains a `\multicolumn` . This generates the LaTeX error !Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit. 
In addition, the line that I input starts further to the right of the table and not all the way to the left as it should.
Here is a minimal example of the code:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart}
 \usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
 \usepackage{tabularx}

 \begin{document}
  \begin{table}
  \caption{Table 1}
  \begin{tabular}{llcc}
  \toprule
  \input{no_degree}
  \midrule
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{Vocational training}\\
 & No training & 400 & 35 \\
 \midrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

The table to input, no_degree has the following code:

```
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{No info on secondary degree}} & 214 & 20 \\
```

Running this generates the error. 
However, when I just copy and paste exactly the content of the inputted file, the code runs smoothly. 
This code is the following:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart}
 \usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
 \usepackage{tabularx}

 \begin{document}
  \begin{table}
  \caption{Table 1}
  \begin{tabular}{llcc}
  \toprule
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{No info on secondary degree}}&214& 20 \\
  \midrule
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{Vocational training}\\
 & No training & 400 & 35 \\
 \midrule
 \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `\csname @@input\endcsname no_degree `

Comment: your mwe works fine, of course if you add missing `\end{table}`

Comment: Using `\csname` works! Thank you!
I forgot `\end{table} `, but had it when I ran the code and it still gave me errors. I added `\end{table}` in the example.

Comment: @Zarko no you can't have a multicolumn in the first cell if you use `\input{}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, apparently i don't understand the question. sorry for noise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not have any non-expandable commands before `\multicolumn`as once a non expandable token is seen the column cell is started and it is too late to make a spanning cell.  unfortunately the LaTeX `\input` command is non-expandable, to add the brace syntax however you can use the primitive input as

```
\csname @@input\endcsname no_degree
```

or

```
 \@@input no_degree
```

if you are in a region where `@` is a letter.

the primitive input is expandable and does not prevent a `\multicolumn` in the file  from working.

Comment: So, I have exactly the same problem as above, but I don't understand the answer (which solved the problem, apparently). Where in my script should I put the lines you wrote, @David Carlisle? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Roland if you have  `\input{whatever-your-file-is-called}` in a tabular then replace it by `\csname @@input\endcsname whatever-your-file-is-called `