# Change catcode of @ in a tabular environment inside a beamer frame

Tags: tables, beamer, catcodes

In order to input data from a file into a `tabular` environment, the TeX macro `\@@input` has to be used (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50694/cannot-use-toprule-when-doing-input-inside-tabular-why)), since `\input` is non-expandable. Why is it not possible to change the catcode in a tabular contained in a beamer frame, e.g.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \makeatletter \@@input file \makeatother
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Although this does not give any errors, it only outputs `@input file`.

Why do I have to use `\csname @@input\endcsname file` (see David Carlisle's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432279/misplaced-omit-error-when-inputting-table-with-multicolumn))?

Comment: Works fine for me. Show a *complete* example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, the problem is, that it is inside a beamer frame and catcode changing is not possible. Shall I delete the question?

Comment: It's much better to say, in the preamble, `\makeatletter\newcommand{\expandableinput}[1]{\@@input #1\relax}\makeatother` and use `\expandableinput{file}` in the document. This will work independently of the document class.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria Do as egreg says. Just for an explanation: `beamer` frames collect their contents, so it's like you used a catcode change (`\makeatletter`) in the argument of a command, which does not work.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ok, thank you! But shouldn't I delete the question since the catcode change does work outside a beamer frame?

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria No, you should add to your question a minimal example that demonstrates your issue, so that other users who try this will see that it doesn't work with `beamer` (this is why people here ask for minimal examples _so much_). You could use: `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \makeatletter\@@input file \makeatother
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`, which is enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ok, thank you. Is it ok so? But isn't it a duplicate now?

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria Yes, much better now, thanks! Yes, it could be a duplicate (there are hundreds of questions whose answer is "`beamer` grabs the `frame` contents: use `\begin{frame}[fragile]`"), but I couldn't find one that seemed an okay duplicate. If you know of one, you can mark your own question as duplicate, if you like. Otherwise, you can leave it as is, no problem in that either.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you very much! Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria No problem ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using `@`-commands in the document body anyway.

If you plan to use `\@@input`, add

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tableinput}[1]{\@@input #1 }
\makeatother
```

to your document preamble and use

```latex
\tableinput{file}
```

in the document.

Beware that this will create spurious spaces in other contexts.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have replaced `\relax` with a space in order to make it work `\bottomrule` (the last line of file already includes \\\).

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria I see the reason, so I modified the code.